# ¿Cómo puedo usar markdown en android Studio?

Tags: android, markdown

Estoy creando una aplicación que busca enseñar los conceptos básicos de `python` y me gustaría a la hora de mostrar un código que este aparezca como tal, que se vea así:

```
#Programa que imprima los 25 primeros numeros naturales
n = 1
while n <= 25: 
print n,
n += 1
```

Que la persona que esta leyendo la teoría y los ejemplos de código lo vea bien en la cuestión de diseño. He visto que varias aplicaciones que enseñan a programar lo hacen y se ve muy bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes emplear este componente, [CodeView](https://github.com/avraampiperidis/Codeview), lo he usado varias veces y me parece genial para lo que buscas https://github.com/avraampiperidis/Codeview.

En resumen es un `WebView` al cual le puedes establecer un diseño que conjuga el estilo de las palabras reservadas del lenguaje, tanto como el fondo de las palabras normales y el background del mismo. Junto con una serie de lenguajes entre los cuales se encuentra el que necesitas. En la página de github está bastante explicado pero bueno aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
WebView wview = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.fwebView);
//Aqui va el codigo que quieres mostrar
String code =   "#Programa que imprima los 25 primeros numeros naturales
                "n = 1\n"+
                "while n <= 25:\n"+ 
                "print n,\n"+
                "n += 1\n";

Codeview.with(getApplicationContext())
        .setLang(Settings.Lang.PYTHON)
        .setStyle(Settings.WithStyle.DARKSTYLE)
        .withCode(code)
        .into(wview);
```